# Getting the line number of a string

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a very long string taken from a file:

```
 lf = open(filename, 'r')
 text = lf.readlines()    
 lf.close()
```

or

```
lineList = [line.strip() for line in open(filename)]
text = '\n'.join(lineList)
```

How can one find specific regular expression's line number in this string( in this case the line number of 'match'):

```
 regex = re.compile(somepattern)
 for match in re.findall(regex, text):
      continue
```

Thank you for your time in advance

Edit: Forgot to add that the  pattern that we are searching  is multiple lines and I am interested in the starting line.

Answer (score 2):

We need to get `re.Match` objects rather than strings themselves using `re.finditer`, which will allow getting information about starting position. Consider following example: lets say I want to find every two digits which are located immediately before and after newline (`\n`) then:

```
import re
lineList = ["123","456","789","ABC","XYZ"]
text = '\n'.join(lineList)
for match in re.finditer(r"\d\n\d", text, re.MULTILINE):
    start = match.span()[0]  # .span() gives tuple (start, end)
    line_no = text[:start].count("\n")
    print(line_no)
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

Explanation: After I get starting position I simply count number of newlines before that place, which is same as getting number of line. Note: I assumed line numbers are starting from `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
lf = open(filename, 'r')
text_lines = lf.readlines()    
lf.close()

regex = re.compile(somepattern)
for line_number, line in enumerate(text_lines):
  for match in re.findall(regex, line):
    print('Match found on line %d: %s' % (line_number, match))
```

Comment: This (trivially) works if the regex doesn't span a line boundary, but it's not clear from the question if that is the case for the OP.

Comment: Yes  indeed I forgot to add this in my question. Now it is there after I saw the answer. Sorry for the misunderstanding. The regex is sadly multiple line pattern.